# htaccess rewrite url de directorio a archivo.html

Tags: reescritura-url, mod-rewrite

Buenas, estoy intentando redireccionar y/o reescribir un set de URLs.

Ejemplo:

```
misitio.com/categoria1 --> misitio.com/categoria1.html
```

Por ahora tengo esto, que me reescribe correctamente este primer nivel:

```
RewriteRule ^categoria1/(\w+)$ $1.html [QSA,L]
```

Sin embargo, no consigo dar con la expresión regular condicional si hubiese más categorias anidadas y tuviese que coger la última como modelo para la URL de salida.

Ejemplo:

```
misitio.com/categoria1/categoria2/categoria3 --> misitio.com/categoria3.html
```

O bien

Ejemplo:

```
misitio.com/categoria1/categoria2/categoria3/categoria4/categoria5/ --> misitio.com/categoria5.html
```

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable? Gracias!

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta no es muy clara, deberías agregar un poco mas de detalle.

Comment: Básicamente intento redireccionar con mod_rewrite, en .htaccess, un set de antiguas urls con múltiples subdirectorios a un único archivo html, tomando como nombre de ese archivo html el nombre de la última categoría anidada. URL original: www.misitio.com/tienda/categoria1/categoria2 --> deberia reescribirse en www.misitio.com/categoria2.html

Comment: Ese código no funciona 500 internal server error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar algo como esto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Esta regla toma el último directorio de la URL y redirecciona al archivo del mismo nombre (terminado en .html). Nota: la regla cubre cualquier palabra y no sólo la cadena "categoriaXYZ", espero que eso esté bien.

Lo bueno: es genérico y con una regla cubres todos los casos. <strike>Lo malo: la URL debe terminar con "/" o no se hará la redirección.</strike> Gracias al [aporte de Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3437/htaccess-rewrite-url-de-directorio-a-archivo-html#comment108474_3448), el código ahora hace que la "/" sea opcional.

Comment: Gracias! Algo parecido pude sacar en claro, pero también me sirve para futuros Rewrites!

Comment: La `/` del final se puede hacer opcional con `([^/]+)/?$`

Comment: @Mariano gracias por el comentario. He actualizado la respuesta con la mejora que sugieres